# ¿Cómo crear una tabla con un nombre aleatorio?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Quisiera crear una tabla en *SQL* que tenga un nombre aleatorio, más en específico estoy usando *DB Browser for SQLite*, que es un gestor de *SQLite*.

Traté de hacer lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE random() (
    Texto_1   TEXT
);
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Resultado: near ")": syntax error
>     En la línea 1:
>     CREATE TABLE random()

Si esto es posible, además me gustaría combinar un texto estático con el número aleatorio:

```
CREATE TABLE "tabla_"+random() (
    Texto_1   TEXT
);
```

Pero aparece el siguiente error:

> Resultado: near "+": syntax error
>     En la línea 1:
>     CREATE TABLE "tabla_"+

Si escribo `random(` me aparece un mensaje:

> RANDOM() La función random() devuelve un entero pseudo-aleatorio entre -9223372036854775808 y +9223372036854775807

¿Es posible hacer esto? ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Por qué querrías crear una tabla con un nombre que no conocerás? Creo que tienes un problema de diseño.

Comment: @LuisCazares Es para hacer pruebas, luego quizás pueda filtrar todas las tablas que comiencen con tal palabra y unirlas o hacer alguna otra operación.

Comment: @ArtEze jamas se me ocurriria algo asi, en la locura hay mucha sabiduria

Comment: Para hacer pruebas, puedes hacer un respaldo de la base de datos y restaurarlo. Necesitas crear la estructura correcta y en todo caso agregar una columna para identificar la prueba que estás realizando. Lo que propones es complicarte la existencia de forma gratuita.

Comment: Lo usas con algún lenguaje de programación en especial? si no se podría dejar de ese lado

Comment: @EdgarVazquez No, ningún lenguaje, aún no sé cómo hacer eso, solo uso el gestor.

Comment: Es que en Sqlite no puedes usar variables como en MYSQL O SQL Server entonces no puedes declarar una vaiable y asiganar el valor ahi y posteriormente crearlo, entonces podrias usar un lenguaje de programacón y de ese lado formar la tabla como string con el nombre random y todo y ya luego solo lo mandas a ejecutar en sql lite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo te comento lo siguiente.

En Sqlite no puedes usar variables como en MYSQL O SQL Server entonces no puedes declarar una variable y asignar el valor random ahi, y posteriormente crearlo, entonces podrías usar un lenguaje de programación y de ese lado formar la tabla como string con el nombre random y todo y ya luego solo lo mandas a ejecutar en sql lite.

Te anexo unos ejemplos de lo que te menciono.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578890/how-do-i-create-tables-dynamically-in-sqlite-in-android
>
> https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/71023-creating-a-dynamic-database-table-in-sqlite3/
>
> https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1189573

Como podras ver todos se apoyan de uso de un lenguaje para que de ese lado se cree la tabla como string y luego ejecutar el comando creado.

Saludos

Comment: Parece que tengo un problema con _IPv4_ e _IPv6_ o algo del _DNS_ de modo que no puedo ver el segundo y tercer enlace. En cuanto pueda lo miro.

Comment: Claro saludos...

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @Luis Cazares, es probable que tengas un error de concepto o diseño, pero si lo queres hacer, deebrías hacerlo desde el lenguaje de programación, aplicando un random, en php y mysql seria algo así:

```
$query="CREATE TABLE ".rand(5, 15)." (
    Texto_1   TEXT
)";
mysqli_query($query,$conexion);
```

Answer (score 1):

mira no se como se realice en SQLite, yo lo hice en sql server y supongo que la sintaxis debe ser parecida espero te sirva de ayuda.

```
declare @nombre_tabla varchar (15) --declaras una variable del nombre de la tabla
declare @sql nvarchar (100),@paramDef nvarchar(100) --declaras variables dinamicas para ejecutar la sentencia
select @nombre_tabla = 'uno' --se asigna el nombre de la tabla

--aqui se crea la tabla que en este caso tendra como nombre final "tabla_uno"
    select @sql = N'create table tabla_'+@nombre_tabla+'(
                columna varchar(50)
                )'
            select @paramDef = N' @nombre_tabla varchar(15)'
            exec sp_executesql @sql, @paramDef, @nombre_tabla
```

Esto lo dorias hacer dentro de un stored procedure, pasando como parámetro el nombre, espero que te pueda ayudar a guiarte e implementarlo en sqllite.
Saldos.

Comment: Al parecer no hay `declare` en _SQLite_. `Resultado: near "declare": syntax error En la línea 1: declare`... ¿Por casualidad no sabes algún equivalente para _SQLite_?

Comment: Si es _SQL Server_, en vez de `"uno"`, me gustaría ver cómo sería con un número aleatorio.

Comment: Te gustaria que sea en SQL Server entonces? si es asi edita tu pregunto y te anexo como @ArtEze

Comment: @EdgarVazquez En realidad no... Me serviría más una respuesta diciendo que no se puede y aceptarla tal como explicaste en el otro comentario, si alguien encuentra la manera de hacerlo dejaría de aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: Que lenguaje estas usando para trabajar con SQLite, por lo que deberías crear dicha tabla desde el lenguaje de programación y después solo mandar la sentencia a SQLite.

Comment: No estoy usando ningún lenguaje adicional, solamente el programa _DB Browser for SQLite_ en la sección de **Ejecutar SQL**.

Answer (score 1):

Un dato clave "dinámico" como podría ser un nombre de tabla o columna, no es algo contemplado en el estándar SQL. Las sentencias SQL deben ser completas, sin referencias no resueltas.

Para poder escribir de forma parametrizada (random o no random) un nombre de tabla, columna o cualquier dato clave en una sentencia SQL (no importa el motor), es necesario "generar" el código de forma dinámica. Lo motores "grandes" en general, resuelven esto, permitiendo escribir la sentencia dinámicamente en primer lugar, por ejemplo en una variable y/o columna y luego ejecutarla. Por ejemplo, **SqlServer** tiene un procedimiento: `sp_executesql`, **Mysql** la cláusula `EXECUTE`, etc.

**Sqlite** no tiene ninguna funcionalidad al respecto (tampoco la necesita), lo que escribes es lo que se compila/ejecuta finalmente. El tema es que normalmente, se usa **Sqlite** integrado con algún otro lenguaje, y es en este lenguaje, en el que eventualmente podrías crear una sentencia SQL con un nombre de tabla parametrizado, sea random o no.